# breeze Validator formatTemplate bug

Tags: validation, breeze

When context value, that is rendered to template, equals 0, value is not inserted to validation message.

I have custom validator:

```
breeze.Validator.min = function(context) {
    var fn = function(val, ctx) { return min <= ctx.min; }
    return new breeze.Validator('min', fn, context);
}
breeze.Validator.messageTemplates.min = "Insert value >= %min%";
```

for validator: `breeze.Validator.min({min: 0})` and negative number I get error message "Insert value >= "

Comment: If you use 1 it is showing up?

Comment: Yes. I saw the code of formatTemplate function, there is weak check for existence of parameter value, inserted to message template, and 0 is translated as "no value".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just confirmed that it is a bug. It will be fixed in the next release 1.4.12 out in a few days, or you can pull the latest code from the Breeze.Js github repo where it has already been fixed.

Comment: I'll use my fixed copy of breeze.js till release.
Also about bugs, was email regex pattern fixed for email validator? I found out that it missed ignorecase flag.

Comment: Yes, that should also already be fixed in the current github repo.